# How to convert a character date into POSIX time without loss in precision

Tags: r, date, posixct

I have the following date which I want to convert into POSIX time. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457212/1707938) but there's a difference between the input and the output date if I convert the date back.

```
char_date <- "2012-04-27T20:48:14"
unix_date <- as.integer(as.POSIXct(char_date, origin="1970-01-01"))
unix_date
# [1] 1335448800
```

which translates back to Thu, 26 Apr 2012 14:00:00.

What am I messing up?

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: Sydney, Australia. But the timestamp was taken in Central Europe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `sub` and you should always define the time zone:

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2012-04-27T20:48:14", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="CET")
#[1] "2012-04-27 20:48:14 CEST"
as.numeric(x)
#[1] 1335552494
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 issue in play here: The `T` character is affecting the character parser so it ingores the time part, and I assume your timezone is UTC+10, which is why your translation is at 2pm the previous day.

```
(as.POSIXct(char_date, origin="1970-01-01"))
[1] "2012-04-27 BST"

(as.POSIXct(sub("T"," ",char_date), origin="1970-01-01"))
[1] "2012-04-27 20:48:14 BST"
```

Comment: Should I indicate the time where the timestamp was taken or mine? `(as.POSIXct(sub("T"," ",char_date), origin="1970-01-01", tz="CET"))`?

Comment: @CptNemo Depends on what you think, but if you dont give one, it will assume the local timezone of your machine, so you will need to be consistent.